# Django, How to display 2 models on a Listview

Tags: django, listview

**I am working with my first Django project**

```
**model.py**
class product(models.Model):
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class stock_product(models.Model):
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    branch_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    quantity  = models.IntegerField(default=0)                          
    price = models.DecimalField(default=0)

**views.py**
class productList(ListView):
    model = product
    template_name = 'product/product_list.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(productList, self).get_queryset()
        self.filterset = productFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=queryset)
        return self.filterset.qs
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = self.filterset
        return context

**product_list.html**
    {% for alist in product_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ alist.product_code }}</td>
            <td>{{ alist.product_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ alist.price }}</td>
            <td>{{ alist.quantity }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Sample Data in tables

```
**product**
['11111','paper'
 '22222','Wood']
**stock_product**
['11111','BR1',150, 10
 '11111','BR2',120, 10
 '11111','BR3',100, 15
 '22222','BR1',50, 200
 '22222','BR2',70, 200
 '22222','BR3',40, 250]
```

I want to get price and quantity from stock_product model, we can change branch_code by user
how can we do Plese help.
Thanks, But I want display only user branch (if user branch 'BR1' display only 'BR1')

Comment: Please use a `ForeignKey` to link a `stock_product` to a `product` object. Not by using the same `product_code`.

Comment: Thanks, But I'm confused about branch_code,How to put branch_code to listview query

Comment: Thanks, But I want display only user branch (if user branch 'BR1' display only 'BR1')

Answer (score 2):

```
**views.py**
class productList(ListView):
    model = product
    template_name = 'product/product_list.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(productList, self).get_queryset()
        self.filterset = productFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=queryset)
        return self.filterset.qs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        stock = stock_product.objects.all(). # this line added
        context['filter'] = self.filterset
        context['stock'] = stock  # this line added
        return context
```

Now having this you can access the `stock` from your template:

```
**product_list.html**
{% for alist in product_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ alist.product_code }}</td>
        <td>{{ alist.product_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ alist.price }}</td>
        <td>{{ alist.quantity }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
{% for s in stock %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ s.product_code }}</td>
        <td>{{ s.product_branch }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

**BUT I have to just do not recommend you do this.** Why? well, I suppose you want to make the match of the `product_code`. Except of that you should use ForeignKey on the models and so you will have a much simple code and logic:

Model:

```
class stock_product(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # this
    branch_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    quantity  = models.IntegerField(default=0)                          
    price = models.DecimalField(default=0)
```

And so now **without modifying your view** you could do this on the template to access the data:

template:

```
{% for alist in product_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ alist.product_code }}</td>
        <td>{{ alist.product_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ alist.stock_product.branch_code }}</td>
        <td>{{ alist.stock_product.quantity }}</td>
        <td>{{ alist.stock_product.price }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: you say "without modifying your view", but then what is assigned in the `ListView` `model =` ? Which model, is it one, or both?

Comment: the same that is on the original post. `model = Product`. As you can see, in the template you arre accessing the product item `alist`, and then you access the `stock_product` directly to refer to the `branch_code`, `quantity` and `price`. With a foreign key, you can access the related models just that simple:  `model.relatedModel.field`.

Comment: thank you but I'm a little confused: the model `Product` does not contain a `ForeignKey`, it is in `stock_product` - yet does it still work? In my own Django project where I was struggling to achieve the same, I used the model containing the `ForeignKey` and it worked. So, does it not matter which of the models you supply to the `ListView` as long as the models are connected via a `ForeignKey`?

Answer (score 1):

how about change the model with using foreign keys.
and use the [django_tables2](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

```
# **model.py**
from django.db import models
class product(models.Model):
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class stock_product(models.Model):
    # product_code = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    product = models.ForeignKey(product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    branch_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    quantity  = models.IntegerField(default=0)                          
    price = models.DecimalField(default=0)
```

this is table code for django_tables2.

```
class DetailedDataTable(tables.Table):
    product_code = tables.Column(verbose_name='product_code', accessor='product_id')
    product_name = tables.Column(verbose_name='product_name', accessor='product_id')

    class Meta:
        model = stock_product
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap.html"
        fields = ('product_code', 'product_name', 'branch_code', 'quantity', 'price')
        
    def render_product_code(self,value, record):
        return product.objects.get(id=value).product_code

    def render_product_name(self,value, record):
        return product.objects.get(id=value).product_name
```

and this is view

```
def view(request):
    template_name = 'template.html'
    query_set = stock_product.objects.all()
    table = DetailedDataTable(qs)
    context={
        'table':table,
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

and this is for template page uses.

```
{# tutorial/templates/tutorial/people.html #}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% render_table table %}
    </body>
</html>
```

:)

Comment: Thanks, Can get it only a branch? 
I want display only user branch (if user branch 'BR1' display only 'BR1')

Comment: then , modify the queryset. query_set = stock_product.objects.filter(branch_code='BR1'). with this, the query_set will only have filtered value.